# org.jboss.util.NotImplementedException when consuming a soap webservice in jboss-5.1.0 GA server

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, jboss5.x, ws-security

I am testing my webservice client code  which  consumes  a soap webservice which aslo needs ws-security authentication. I used apache cxf 2.3.0, wss4j 1.5.9,apache-cxf-rt-security 2.3.0 jars. However i am getting the below exception when my code is deployed in jboss-5.1.0 GA. When i tested it on jetty server it works fine. Any help is highly appreciated.

stack trace below

> org.jboss.util.NotImplementedException
>       at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPPartImpl.appendChild(SOAPPartImpl.java:298)
>       at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.W3CDOMStreamWriter.setChild(W3CDOMStreamWriter.java:114)
>       at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.W3CDOMStreamWriter.newChild(W3CDOMStreamWriter.java:104)
>       at org.apache.cxf.staxutils.W3CDOMStreamWriter.writeStartElement(W3CDOMStreamWriter.java:132)
>       at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.writeSoapEnvelopeStart(SoapOutInterceptor.java:122)
>       at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:81)
>       at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:61)
>       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:247)
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:516)
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:313)
>       at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:265)
>       at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
>       at $Proxy328.documentVerificatieSysteem(Unknown Source)
>       at com.experian.nextgen.nl.services.reporting.helper.RDCWebserviceHelper.getRDCResult(RDCWebserviceHelper.java:159)
>       at com.experian.nextgen.nl.facades.impl.RDCWSFacadeService.invoke(RDCWSFacadeService.java:57)
>       at com.experian.nextgen.nl.services.jbpm.tasks.ThirdPartyRDCSearchTask.invoke(ThirdPartyRDCSearchTask.java:70)
>       at com.experian.nextgen.core.services.jbpm.tasks.NGAbstractJbpmTask.execute(NGAbstractJbpmTask.java:129)
>       at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.wire.usercode.UserCodeActivityBehaviour.execute(UserCodeActivityBehaviour.java:42)
>       at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.model.op.ExecuteActivity.perform(ExecuteActivity.java:60)
>       at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.model.ExecutionImpl.performAtomicOperationSync(ExecutionImpl.java:672)
>       at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.model.ExecutionImpl.performAtomicOperation(ExecutionImpl.java:632)
>       at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.model.ExecutionImpl.start(ExecutionImpl.java:217)
>       at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.cmd.StartProcessInstanceInLatestCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceInLatestCmd.java:63)
>       at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.cmd.StartProcessInstanceInLatestCmd.execute(StartProcessInstanceInLatestCmd.java:36)
>       at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.DefaultCommandService.execute(DefaultCommandService.java:42)
>       at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.tx.StandardTransactionInterceptor.execute(StandardTransactionInterceptor.java:50)
>       at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.EnvironmentInterceptor.executeInNewEnvironment(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:53)
>       at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.EnvironmentInterceptor.execute(EnvironmentInterceptor.java:40)
>       at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.RetryInterceptor.execute(RetryInterceptor.java:56)
>       at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.SkipInterceptor.execute(SkipInterceptor.java:43)
>       at org.jbpm.pvm.internal.svc.ExecutionServiceImpl.startProcessInstanceByKey(ExecutionServiceImpl.java:71)
>       at com.experian.nextgen.core.services.jbpm.impl.NGGenericJbpmServiceImpl.run(NGGenericJbpmServiceImpl.java:71)
>       at com.experian.nextgen.nl.services.eidcheck.impl.EidCheckService.getEidCheckReport(EidCheckService.java:42)
>       at com.experian.nextgen.nl.services.webservices.autotrace.impl.AutoTraceWSImpl.getEidCheckReport(AutoTraceWSImpl.java:951)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>       at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:173)
>       at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:89)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JAXWSMethodInvoker.invoke(JAXWSMethodInvoker.java:60)
>       at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:75)
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>       at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:106)
>       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:247)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:113)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletDestination.invoke(ServletDestination.java:97)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:458)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:185)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractCXFServlet.invoke(AbstractCXFServlet.java:148)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:179)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:103)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:159)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
>       at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
>       at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
>       at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)